# Multiple LAG/LEAD with different offsets - how to avoid code duplication

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've query like this:

```
SELECT
 LAG(col, 1) OVER(w) AS c_1,
 LAG(col, 2) OVER(w) AS c_2,
 ...
 LAG(col, 12) OVER(w) AS c_12,
 other_col,
FROM table
WINDOW w AS (...)
```

so a lot of code duplication for LAGs. 
It is barely manageable with 12 - 12 months, but what about days(365)? It'd be great to have construct like `LAG(col, [1,2,..,365]) OVER(w) AS c_1, c_2, ..., c_365`

Is there some standard or vendor specific (google bigquery but could be also ohter), way to deal with this?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: There is no way you can do that in SQL. It does not allow to define multiple output columns with a single expression. Depending on your DBMS, you could aggregate all those `c_XXX` columns into a (single) JSON value or array.

Comment: Having 365 nearly identical columns is not necessary. In Oracle I would think about a custom aggregation function and a nested table.

Comment: What do you really want to solve? Do you really want a resulting table with 356+ columns?

Comment: For now, I want to have less code duplication for just 12 but It'd be great to have general solution for any `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put the results in arrays.  This assumes that the rows for `lag()`s exist -- i.e. months/days are not skipped.

In that case, something like this:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ARRAY(SELECT el
             FROM unnest(vals) el WITH OFFSET n
             ORDER BY n DESC
             LIMIT 12
            ) ar
FROM (select t.*, array_agg(y) over (partition by id order by x) as vals
      from t
     ) t;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use `LIMIT`/`ORDER BY` with `ARRAY_AGG()` as a window function.  Instead, this aggregates everything together and then uses array operations to get the last 12 or 365 or whatever values.